# SSD HD Partition MIssing Space

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have a 225gb SSD with a 216gb boot partition with windows installed.

The disk is reading 11.2 GB of free space, however I can only locate ~90GB of data (analysing the contents including hidden files/folders).

I have used Space Sniffer and WinDirStat to try and find what's filling it.  A few minutes in - both apps crash (presumably finding something that causes the crash).

I have run Error checking on the disk, and chkdsk and everything comes back fine.  I'm lost as to what to try next?

Comment: Try WizTree which uses a different method than WinDirStat. Also did those programs output logs about the crash?

Comment: I think WizTree has found the problem.  It gets to [user]\AppData\Roaming\com.adobe.dunamis and then seems to take an age trying to discover whats in the folder (which reports as only being a few kb).

A quick google of the folder suggests other people having issues with logs from Adobe apps clogging up their HDD from here.  I have an issue with Illustrator so likely to be related.  Will report back once I've concluded.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that Adobe CC has a folder full of 20m+ empty folders in c:\users[user]\appdata\roaming\com.adobe.dunamis.  The apps have been crashing when trying to calculate the size of the folders, as is the delete functionality.

I understand this is because Windows tries to calculate the size of the directory before it deletes it.

To resolve the issue, I am now manually deleting the above folder by navigating to the folder in command prompt and running `rmdir com.adobe.dunamis /s /q`.

This will take a while to complete, but will not try and calculate the size of the directory before getting to work on deleting the folders.

Comment: What does this mean? Is this an answer? if you want to add more info to your question, feel free to edit your question to do so. But please do not add an “answer” like this unless it is indeed the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).